# React-modal: dropzone activates file-explorer upon exit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button that activates a modal on mouse-over nested inside a dropzone,

[image]

When I exit the modal by clicking (not escaping--escaping always works), the dropzone housing the button activates the file explorer, no matter where I click.

The modal is created using `react-modal` (not bootstrap), and the html reads:

```
<Modal
    isOpen={props.state.show}

    onRequestClose={props.handleClose}
    shouldReturnFocusAfterClose={false}

    shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={true}
    shouldCloseOnEscape={true} >
    ...
 </Modal>
```

How do I avoid activating the dropzone (react-dropzone) when click-exiting the Modal?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the Modal adds an overlay that is (if looking at the DOM tree) inside the dropzone, so clicking on it means clicking in the dropzone which will trigger the default action for the dropzone, which is opening a file explorer.

The solution for you is the `disableClick` property of the `react-dropzone`. Since you already manage a state in which you control whether the modal is open, you can use that same variable to set the `disableClick` property to `props.state.show` for the `dropzone` which prevents opening the file explorer on clicks for the time the modal is open.

You can see examples of `disableClick` at: https://react-dropzone.js.org/#dropzone

Comment: Awesome thanks man.  Will accept when I get a chance to try it out